# How to overwrite data from a model that is linked to the main model through a o-t-m relationship?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have three models that are related to each other, namely:

**models.py**

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(ShopCity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

class ProductQuantity(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=None)
```

In the admin panel they are linked in this way:

**admin.py**

```
class ProductQuantityInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductQuantity
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name', 'price']
    list_display = ['name', 'price']
    inlines = [ProductQuantityInline]
```

There is a need to overwrite data with REST API

**serializers.py**

```
class QuantitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductQuantity
        fields = ('shop', 'quantity')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    productquantity = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'price', 'productquantity')

    def get_productquantity(self, obj):
        return [QuantitySerializer(s).data for s in obj.productquantity_set.all()]
```

And finally my handler for REST API:

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def api_product_detail(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'PUT' or request.method == 'PATCH':
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        product.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

As a result, data such as the **name** and **price** are overwritten, and the **productquantity** is not overwritten.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: `productquantity` is a `SerializerMethodField`, and it's read-only (you can't force it to be writable) so it's normal behaviour that it's not overwritten. Relationship with DRF are complex and not obvious so it's better you overwrite the create() and update() method of your serializers so you know how they are going to behave.

Comment: I have overridden the method update()

`def update`

but unfortunately I see the same picture